# Lightweight way to trigger local build from github repository commit?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, gnu-make

Our GitHub project builds with a simple "make all", but internally is complex enough to make using CI systems like Travis CI or Jenkins to fail too often to be useful. We have an internal repository and CI system, so all I'm looking for is something like a script that waits for a GitHub master commit, pulls it and rebuilds locally using the same tools and libraries I use in daily development. No containers, no public cloud or CI sites, just really simple. Does anyone know of such a script?

Comment: Run `git fetch` in a loop, and compare the results of `git rev-parse` for local and remote branches? Or, quick googling found this: https://github.com/kolbasa/git-repo-watcher, which does essentially that.
Side note: if your environment is hard to reproduce, then it's a ticking bomb.

Comment: Thanks for the repo-watcher link, looks useful. There's no bombs in our project :-), but because it's a Java compiler and runtime for iOS, it can only be built on a Mac due to iOS SDK licensing, and needs up-to-date Java support, and takes over an hour to build due to how big the Java runtime test suite is.